# Incrementing 5 digit number, including leading zeros

Tags: vba, ms-access

I need to generate statement numbers in Access 2016. These numbers need to be 5 digits long, and where the statement number is less than 5 digits, I need to pad the number with leading zeros.

As a starting point, the first statement number will not be padded. So if the last statement number is 96, the next statement number needs to be 00097.

Is it possible (I assume in VBA) to cater for both cases, where the number is 5 digits long, or where it is less.

I was thinking of firstly stripping the leading zeros from the last statement number (if any existed), incrementing the remaining number by one, and then adding leading zeros to make the length of the number 5, but I'm not sure of the most efficient way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it has a leading zero, it will not be a number, but a String. However, as far as it is not quite a bit difference, something like this works:

```
Sub TestMe()
    Dim cnt         As Long
    Dim myString    As String
    For cnt = 98 To 120
        myString = Format(cnt, "00000")
        Debug.Print myString
    Next cnt
End Sub
```

This is what you get in the immediate window:

```
00098
00099
00100
00101
```

Comment: I setup a string variable NextStateStr, and a Long variable LastStateNum. I can see in the immediate window 00005 (the correct value), but when I use NextStateStr, it is actually 5??

Comment: @user1936588 - "If it has a leading zero, it will not be a number, but a String. " This means that you should declare the value as `String`, not as `Long`.

Comment: @user1936588 - What `LastStateNum` is and how did it become 4?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. The last statement number will be saved as a number in all cases. In my example, the value is 4, so my next value (which needs to be a string) is 00005. I will then save the value 5 to the database.

Comment: It does. Sorry - I set NextStateStr as Long also in erro. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just first convert to a number:

```
NextValue = Format(Val(CurrentValue) + 1, "00000")
```

Comment: Same comment to you as Vityata

Answer (score 0):

You could also use:

```
NextStateStr = Right("00000" & LastStateNum + 1, 5)
```